# Scrollbar for android 2.3 apart from iscroll4

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I tried iscroll4 plug-in for my android 2.3/cordova  app development. But since i am not able to get the scroller location(position) dynamically in javascript by using:

```
document.getElementById("home").scrollTop = scroll_val;
```

, its of no use to me. If anybody can suggest any other plugin for scrolling in android 2.3 in which i can get/set scrollbar position through javascript/jquery. Basically, i my app, i have a static header and footer and the content(div) in between is to be scrolled when available space exceeds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used Overthrow (https://github.com/filamentgroup/Overthrow/) for a project in Phonegap and android 2.3.
The performance is not the best, but works...
Hope this help someone.